# Non-blocking way to offer + drainTo for a BlockingQueue (or something else)

Tags: java, concurrency

I am looking for something seemingly simple, a collection with a non-blocking version of "add" and "drain". Something like this:

```
List itemsToProcess = queue.addOrDrainAndAdd( item );
if ( itemsToProcess != null )
    process( items );
```

It seems to me that if I do these as separate "offer" and "drainTo" calls that I could have offer called twice before I get to the first call to drain to. I would also need a loop on something like "while ( !queue.offer( item ) )" so that after it is drained the offer would work, which I think would require me to also check if drain returned an empty collection (because two might call drain). My naive implementation was like this but it doesn't seem optimal:

```
void addBatchItem( T item ) {
   while ( !batch.offer( item ) ) {
       List<T> batched = new ArrayList<>( batchSize );
       batch.drainTo( batched );
       process( batched );
   }
}
```

Then I thought maybe there is a better way and I just don't know it. Thanks!

EDIT:

Okay, so here's a solution (that is blocking based on ArrayBlockingQueue):

```
public void add( T batchItem ) {
    while ( !batch.offer( batchItem ) ) {
        flush();
    }
}

public void flush() {
    List<T> batched = new ArrayList<>( batchSize );
    batch.drainTo( batched, batchSize );
    if ( !batched.isEmpty() )
        executor.execute( new PhasedRunnable( batched ) );
}
```

I guess my question is, would the above be more optimal for this purpose than a solution based on ConcurrentLinkedQueue since the latter requires an object allocation for each node?

EXAMPLE CLASS WITH USAGE:

```
public abstract class Batcher<T> {

    private final int batchSize;
    private ArrayBlockingQueue<T> batch;
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private final Phaser phaser = new Phaser( 1 );

    public Batcher( int batchSize, ExecutorService executor ) {
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
        this.executor = executor;
        this.batch = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>( batchSize );
    }

    public void add( T batchItem ) {
        while ( !batch.offer( batchItem ) ) {
            flush();
        }
    }

    public void flush() {
        List<T> batched = new ArrayList<>( batchSize );
        batch.drainTo( batched, batchSize );
        if ( !batched.isEmpty() )
            executor.execute( new PhasedRunnable( batched ) );
    }

    public abstract void onFlush( List<T> batch );

    public void awaitDone() {
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
    }

    public void awaitDone( long duration, TimeUnit unit ) throws TimeoutException {
        try {
            phaser.awaitAdvanceInterruptibly( phaser.arrive(), duration, unit );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    private class PhasedRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final List<T> batch;

        private PhasedRunnable( List<T> batch ) {
            this.batch = batch;

            phaser.register();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                onFlush( batch );
            }
            finally {
                phaser.arrive();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple example, a more complete example may be JPA entity updates or inserts. Also, I would like it to be possible for #add to be called concurrently.

```
@Test
public void testOddNumber() {
    Batcher<Integer> batcher = new Batcher<Integer>( 10, executor ) {
        @Override
        public void onFlush( List<Integer> batch ) {
            count.addAndGet( batch.size() );
        }
    };

    for ( int at = 0; at != 21; ++at ) {
        batcher.add( at );
    }

    batcher.flush();
    batcher.awaitDone();

    assertEquals( count.get(), 21 );
}
```

Comment: So the reason you want to do that is in case the queue is full, right?

Comment: In your other comment, you say you don't actually care if it is atomic: what, exactly *is* the crucial? non-blocking add and drain and… what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> seemingly simple, a collection with a non-blocking but atomic version of "add" and "drain"

That is actually impossible.  Non blocking algorithms (on 1-CAS archs) work on a single memory address for atomicity.  So draining an entire queue without blocking and atomically is impossible.

#### Edit:

Based on your edit, I would think that is probably the most efficient way to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: You are right. I don't care that it is atomic per se. I care that I only drain N number of items at a time. It's okay if some are added to the queue while draining since I can control the max items drained. Does that make more sense?

Comment: In the special case he's trying to implement, I don't see why it would be impossible: for example: imagine that the items he wants to add and the items in the queue are both in a linked list: couldn't an implementation atomically swap the head pointers of the two lists?

Comment: @user1888440 Ok, that's slightly different than a non-blocking drainTo.  For instance the BlockingQueue's `drainTo` will result in a drained collection of the exact state when starting.  In your case your implementation would work fine and is probably more optimal then anything else.  The alternative is to use a ConcurrentLinkedQueue for a true non-blocking queue.

Comment: @JVMATL Unless I am not understanding you correctly.  You can only swap one address with another, so A -> B, not A -> && B -> A.  That would require a 2-CAS (which is in the works for standard JDK)

Comment: I've edited my original post with a solution that may be good enough. The question is, am I better off with that or using a ConcurrentLinkedQueue? The advantage of ArrayBlockingQueue is that it does not allocate an object for each node.

Comment: @user1888440 Can you please post that in an edit to your original question?

Comment: @user1888440 2 questions.. 1. Where is `batchSize` set, 2.  Do you really need batchSize?  Can you not just create a variable ArrayList and have it drain all the elements of the queue currently (considering the queue may have changed after collecting `batchSize` and before flush)?

Comment: I'll update the question again to show you the full class and an example usage. I would like to have even batch sizes until the final flush (for any left overs).

Comment: @JohnVint I'd say the odds are good that you are understanding me just fine, but I'm being dense :^) - nevertheless, my thought was an atomic addAndDrain might work by taking a reference to the head of the queue (assume linked list here for simplicity) and then using something like AtomicReference.compareAndSet to swap in the new head of the queue iff the head of the queue was still the same as when we sampled it. (this would have to be part of the implementation of the queue, not something external)

Comment: I think I see the problem; the swap might be atomic, but the state of the queue I drain could change after the swap, because somebody else might be holding a reference to the old queue when we swap. Tricky..

Comment: @JohnVint can you recommend a reference for reading about what 2-CAS would imply? '2-CAS' is a hard thing to google for..

Comment: Exactly! So a single (1CAS) says, 'If memory location A has not changed then swap it with B'  A 2CAS says 'If memory location A has not change and memory location B has not changes swap A with B and B with A' or swap with some other variables C and D (doesn't need to be a reflexive swap).

Comment: @JVMATL  You can google on **multi word compare and swap**.
It's at the very least referenced in a recent JDK9 preliminaries for addition to the JDK http://jsr166-concurrency.10961.n7.nabble.com/JDK9-concurrency-preliminaries-td10493.html.

Comment: @JohnVint thanks, I'm going to accept your answer based on the help you provided even though I believe your last suggestion in that post is incorrect. I'm spinning because "flush()" is the only operation that drains the queue. If I use put I will never get to the flush statement to drain it. The while loop would minimally (if ever) spin because it would be drained by flush. So I flush, and all adders just try again. The put approach would not allow that. Thanks!

Comment: Ooh ok.  I will delete that part, thanks for the update. Thought you were waiting for room to become available.